# PyShp - getting Python to recognise points from a polyline

Tags: python, numpy, shapefile, polyline

I'm rather new to Python, so I suspect this problem I'm having arises from naivety, but any help would be appreciated.

Currently I have a small coastal evolution model. Initially this randomly generates 100 points along a defined x-axis within some constraints, using NumPy. Relevant part of the code is this:

```
# assign the number of points along the beach       
Num_P_Coast  = 100

# node spacing
dx = 10
x_vec = np.zeros(Num_P_Coast)

for i in range(0,Num_P_Coast):
    x_vec[i] = dx*i

# initialize beach and cliff with random numbers
Bch_Width = np.random.uniform(0, 30, Num_P_Coast)
Cl_Loc = np.random.uniform(30, 60, Num_P_Coast)
```

The model then uses these two initial lines for the model computation. What I'm attempting to do is use PyShp to read in a polyline drawn in ArcMap to replace these randomly generated point, which will then be used for the model computation. Code I'm trying is like this:

```
BS1 = shp.Reader("Beach2.shp") #calling shapefile of beach front location
CL1 = shp.Reader("Cliff2.shp") #calling shapefile of cliff location

p1 = BS1.shapes()
b = p1[0]
BeachShp1 = b.points

p2 = CL1.shapes()
c = p2[0]
CliffShp1 = c.points

Bch_Width = np.random.uniform(0, 30, BS1) #Attempt to use polyline of beach to generate    initial beach location
Cl_Loc = np.random.uniform(30, 60, CL1)  #Attempt to use polyline of beach to generate initial beach location
```

This keeps giving errors such as "TypeError: an integer is required" and "ValueError: sequence too large; must be smaller than 32" when i try small changes in the code.

Does anybody know what needs to be done to get the code to accept the points on the polyline, rather than the randomly generated point? I feel like it should be simple, but I've trawled through PyShp documentation and other questions on here and can't seem to find what to do.

Cheers

Full code:

```
def toy_beach_model(): #this is the main part of the program, which will call the     evol_equations function to do all the jiggery pokery of outputting beach evolution

#where do you want to put it
#OutputDirectory = str(raw_input("Enter output directory:"))  
OutputDirectory = 'c:/python_results/graphs/'  
OutputModelName =  eg.enterbox(title = 'Model name', msg = 'Enter model ID:')
ModelDesc = eg.enterbox(title = 'Model description', msg = 'Enter short description of model' )

# assign the number of points along the beach    
Num_P_Coast  = 100

# node spacing
dx = 10
x_vec = np.zeros(Num_P_Coast)

# some parameters
Cl_Eros_NoBch = int(eg.enterbox(title = 'Erosion rate', msg = 'Enter erosion rate:'))


Cl_Eros_HRock = Cl_Eros_NoBch * 0.5 #simulating harder rock = headland evolution

Cl_Eros_Efold = 50

Sup_Rate = int(eg.enterbox(title = 'Sediment supply', msg = 'Enter sediment supply rate:'))
K = 0.5


# set up x vector
for i in range(0,Num_P_Coast):
    x_vec[i] = dx*i

BS1 = shp.Reader("Beach2.shp") #calling shapefile of beach front location
CL1 = shp.Reader("Cliff2.shp") #calling shapefile of cliff location

p1 = BS1.shapes()
b = p1[0]
BeachShp1 = b.points

p2 = CL1.shapes()
c = p2[0]
CliffShp1 = c.points


# initialize beach and cliff with random numbers
#Bch_Width = np.random.uniform(0, 30, Num_P_Coast)
#Cl_Loc = np.random.uniform(30, 60, Num_P_Coast)

Bch_Width = np.random.uniform(0, 30, BeachShp1) #Attempt to use polyline of beach to generate initial beach location
Cl_Loc = np.random.uniform(30, 60, CliffShp1)  #Attempt to use polyline of beach to generate initial beach location


#H_Loc = Cl_Loc
#H_Loc = np.random.uniform(0, 8, Num_P_Coast)    
H_Loc = np.random.random_sample(Num_P_Coast)
BcH_Eros = Bch_Width+Cl_Loc

# lets have this evolve through time

# time spacing in years    
dt = 10

# number of time steps
n_timesteps = int(eg.enterbox(title = 'Timestep', msg = 'Enter number of iterations'))

# set up the beach erosion vector
Cl_Eros = np.zeros(Num_P_Coast)

H_Eros = np.zeros(Num_P_Coast)    

# initial headland erosion
H_Eros = dt*Cl_Eros_HRock*np.exp(-Bch_Width/Cl_Eros_Efold)

# initial erosion
Cl_Eros = dt*Cl_Eros_NoBch*np.exp(-Bch_Width/Cl_Eros_Efold)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you're you're trying to make a (potentially) several thousand dimensional array with `Bch_Width = np.random.uniform(0, 30, BeachShp1)`, etc.

[`numpy.random.uniform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) expects a low, and high, and a shape of the array that will be produced.

For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.random.uniform(0, 5) # Generate a single random number between 0 and 5
Out[2]: 4.149771995503083

In [3]: np.random.uniform(0, 5, 3) # Generate an array of three numbers
Out[3]: array([ 2.25725653,  0.70070352,  0.62541689])

In [4]: np.random.uniform(0, 5, (2,2)) # Generate a 2x2 array of 4 numbers
Out[4]:
array([[ 0.89355128,  3.30796407],
       [ 1.23816971,  1.12224456]])
```

When you run:

```
p1 = BS1.shapes()
b = p1[0]
BeachShp1 = b.points
```

`BeachShp1` is a sequence of x,y coordinates.  Basically, you're trying to do something like:

```
np.random.uniform(low, high, [[19.554, 45.998], [20.889, 24.009], ... ])
```

...which doesn't make any sense.

Are you trying to add a random beach width to the line represented by the shapefile?  Or calculate the distance between the cliff outline and the beach outline?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: Cheers for the answer! I think I see how trying to combine random.uniform and the BeachShp isn't going to work.

I'm hoping the polyline in the shapefile will represent a beach starting 'shape' and position (as well as the corresponding shapefile for the cliff). The purpose of the model is then to run through beach/cliff erosion over time. However the model equations rely on the points generated as the starting position of the beach/cliff. Hence my hoping I could somehow replace those points with an actual drawn outline of a beach to add realism to the model.